# Get destiniation URL using PHP?

Tags: php, redirect

I'd like to redirect the user depending on the destination url and referrer url. Say I have a homepage url `http://www.example.com/` and in that page there are a bunch of links that point to `http://www.example.com/page/x/`. When the user goes to `http://www.example.com/page/` from `http://www.example.com/` it should redirect to another page. But when the user goes to `http://www.example.com/page/x/` via a link from `http://www.example.com/` it should not redirect. In order to achieve this, the solution I am thinking is to get the destination url as well to correctly determine if the user comes from `http://www.example.com/` but wants to view `http://www.example.com/page/x/`. Bottom line is I want to prevent access to `http://www.example.com/page/` but not to its sub pages.

Comment: The referrer URL isn't reliable, it can be easily spoofed. Does this matter?

Comment: @spraff: In my case, I think it doesn't matter since it could be any pages. I'd like to make sure `http://www.example.com/page/` can't be accessed except its sub pages.

Comment: This is a virtual hierarchy of pages rt, or by child page you mean the pages in the folder `page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is scary bad.

You can't rely on the referer being returned by the browser (but it is a good indicator). You could use a generic javascript to rewrite every link on the page to append a CGI variable containing the URIencoded URL of the current page (but where javascript is enabled it won't work). Or you could put rewrite the output buffer to inject CGI vars into hrefs in PHP. Neither of these are trivial - and if they break your users will not be able to navigate.

But leaving aside the implementation for now - your solution seems to be rather absurd.

If the problem is to

> prevent access to http://www.example.com/page/

but allow requests for

> http://www.example.com/page/x/

Then create an index.php in http://www.example.com/page/ with something like....

```
<?php
header('Location: /', true, 301);
?>
```

Or disable auto-index on your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems no one can access the `example.com/page/`, You can have a [Header](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php) function in the `http://www.example.com/page/` to redirect the page to some other page.